# Why isn't it possible to cast an int (representing an ASCII character) to an std::string without curly braces wrapped around the int?

Tags: c++, string, casting

```
int main() {

    std::string A;
    A += (std::string)65;
    std::cout << A;

}
```

The code above does not work. It throws a compiler error. But the code below works.

```
int main() {

    std::string A;
    A += (std::string){65};
    std::cout << A;

}
```

When I wrap the 65 in curly braces, it is interpreted as an ASCII A like I wanted it to be, but without the curly braces, the program doesn't work. I also tried putting multiple numbers in the braces, like so:

```
int main() {

   std::string A;
   A += (std::string){65, 66};
   std::cout << A;

}
```

That would print out AB. I just hope someone can clear this up for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The  second and third work because of this constructor:

```
basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> init, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

That is, whenever the compiler sees the curly braces, it converts `{...}` into an  `std::initializer_list<T>` for a suitable T.

In your case, it converts to `std::initializer_list<char>` which then gets passed to the above mentioned constructor of `std::string`.

Since there exists an overload of `+=` which takes `std::initializer_list<char>`:

```
basic_string& operator+=( std::initializer_list<CharT> ilist );
```

you can write this:

```
std::string s;

s += {65};
s += {66, 67};
```

That should work as well.

Note that you can also write this:

```
s += 65;
```

Even this will work, but for a different reason — it will invoke the following overload:

```
basic_string& operator+=( CharT ch );
```

In this case, `65` (which is `int`) converts into `char` type.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was also reading about uniform initialization, would this be considered it?

Answer (score 3):

`(std::string){65, 66}` is a C99 compound literal, and not valid C++. Some C++ compilers support it as an extension, but they should all complain with sufficiently pedantic settings.

`std::string{65, 66}` (or just `std::string{65}`) works because they construct a temporary `std::string` using its `initializer_list<char>` constructor.

`std::string` has no constructor taking an integer (or a `char`, for that matter), so your cast doesn't work.

Also, `A += 65;` works as well, because `string` has an overloaded `operator+=` taking a `char`. (Unfortunately, this also means that `A += 3.1415926;` "works" too.)

And similarly, `A += {65, 66};` will also work because `string` has an overloaded `operator+=` taking an `initializer_list<char>`.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `(std::string)65` is a cast, i.e. you are trying to convert the number `65` to an `std::string`. Your first example doesn't work because an `int` is not convertible to an `std::string` , since `std::string` does not have any constructor that takes an integer.

Your second and third example work since `A+= (std::string){65}` means "construct a temporary string via its initializer-list constructor (no. 9 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)) and append it to `A`". Note that you could've just written `A+= {65}`, and no temporary will be constructed, since you invoke directly `std::string::operator+=` on a initializer list, no. 4 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D).

Comment: No temporary `string` is constructed in `A+= {65}`.

Comment: @T.C. You're right, I edited, it was not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The first one attempts to reinterpret `65` as `std::string`.
This is not possible, as integers and `std::string`s are completely unrelated.

The second one constructs an instance of `std::string`, passing `65` to its constructor.

The second one works because it is not a cast.

If you drop the unnecessary parentheses, it becomes clearer that it's not a cast - it's equivalent to

```
A += std::string{65};
```

and to

```
A += std::string('A');
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you're using a C-style cast, you're not constructing a `std::string` merely trying to force 65 to be a `std::string`.

Using curly braces for initialization invokes the `initializer_list` ctor so in the second and third example you're actually constructing a `std::string`. That's why it works.